# Best way to structure a database when giving the user the ability to create dynamic fields

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I would like some advice on the best way to structure some models in a django project I have.  I need to give the user the ability to create their own verticals, which dictates what fields the "client" object will have. Here are two example verticals to illustrate this:

Loan
Fields:

```
name (str field)
phone (str field)
loan_amount (int field)
loan_purpose (selection field)
```

Solar
Fields:

```
name (str field)
phone (str field)
house_type (selection field)
budget (int field)
```

So right now I have a Vertical model, and a DataField model that has a foreign key relationship with a vertical.  That way users can dynamically create fields for each vertical they have.

To save incoming clients, I have a Client model.  The Client model has a foreign relationship with a vertical,  so the user knows which vertical it belongs to.  However, since datafields are dynamically set by the user, I can't simply set datafields as fields on the Client model.  As such, I currently have a model called ClientField.  The ClientField has a fk relation to a Client and to a DataField, and also a normal field "value" to store the value of that field.  So when a Client is created, I also create a ClientField for every field in its vertical to store its data.  Here is an Example:

Client

```
id=1
vertical=Loan
```

ClientField

```
id=1
client=1
datafield=name
value="John Smith"
```

ClientField

```
id=2
client=1
datafield=phone
value="0411222333"
```

ClientField

```
id=3
client=1
datafield=loan_amount
value="15000"
```

ClientField

```
id=4
client=1
datafield=loan_purpose
value="Car Financing"
```

So I originally thought this was a fine way to set up a relation database for the project, however after only using it for a short period, the database is already up to 600k rows of ClientFields.  I'm not too experienced with managing databases so maybe I'm overreacting, but I'm starting to wonder if this is the most effecient way to structure this.

The only alternative I can think of is removing the ClientField model and creating a "data" JSON field in the Client model, and saving the data there.  So my client example would just become:

Client

```
id=1
vertical=Loan
data={
name:"John Smith",
phone:"0411222333",
loan_amount:"15000",
loan_purpose:"Car Financing"
}
```

From what I could research, this method would potentially be better for db performance if there starts to be an overwelming amount of ClientFields, but has drawbacks in that querying the database by client data might become very difficult or slow performing.  I'm not really sure on how I can go about judging what would be a more future proof decision?

Or is there another solution to this issue that I am not aware of?  I've never used NoSQL databases before, dunno if this would be the kind of issue they are designed for, but the rest of my app is so suited to relational databases I think it would create a lot more issues.

Comment:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Ok sweet so this is what I'm already doing (and is okay)?

Comment: If the only concern is that you think 600k rows are a lot: it's not. A properly set up and indexed database should have no problems handling billions of rows.

Comment: ok thanks for the help